# Enable VMWare web client?

Tags: vmware, webclient

I have a dedicated server that was upgraded from VMWare Exsi 5.5 to VMWare 6 recently. I used to use the desktop application to control remotely my dedicated server however I kept get a warning since the upgrade that any VM configuration above VMWare V8 will have to use the Web Client to configure in order to be able to configure all aspects of the VM.

However I do not think I actually have web client installed on the machine, when I go to https://MY_VM_IP all I see is a link to download the installer.

How do I enable the web client? If it is enabled how do I access it? Is it via a specific port number?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by `VMWare Web Client`?  I assume you are talking about the vSphere web client.  if that is the case you should clarify your question.

Comment: "However I do not think I actually have web client installed on the machine" - Check to see if your vCenter server is running the required service.

Comment: @Ramhound I checked again the correct name is vSphere web client, the exact error message is here: http://imgur.com/a/gETN3.

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry is vCenter part of EXSi?

Comment: No; It's not...